# problems with LIBSVM on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I have been using [LIBSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) in Matlab on Windows and Linux, and get different results. The Linux version just keeps restarting instead of iterating and gets really bad results.
I tried to recompile and did everything that was on the README file, any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: are win/linux runnning 32/64bit?

Comment: Have you managed to figure this out? I am noticing a somewhat similar difference between Linux and Windows (both x64) and it's really, really strange :|

Comment: Do you really think it is giving the right results in windows?